# Smartphone apps can't read the entirety of long text files? (Orgzly / Filenotes)

Tags: android, text, dropbox

I keep a lot of .txt files synced across all my devices with dropbox, and up until recently I've had no problem accessing them on my phone with an app called Orgzly. However I seem to have hit some sort of character limit as I'm continuously adding to one of these files and while the file is perfectly readable on any PC, Orgzly now seems to cut out near the end of the file. (For reference, I'm now at 1921 words over 37 pages if I paste the contents of the file into a blank word document)

I just tried another app called Filenotes and the exact same thing happens. Perhaps I'm I'm not searching the correct keywords, but a google search is not showing anything remotely useful within the top 50 hits.

So my question is this - Do smartphone operating systems or the app APIs have some sort of built in character limit for files? And is there any sort of workaround to get this file readable on my phone, short of accessing the .txt file via the dropbox app directly? (Which actually works, FYI)

Comment: What is the size of the files? I see no reason why an Android app would not be able to read a GB file.

Comment: `if I paste the contents of the file into a blank word document`. Maybe the paste buffer has limits?

Comment: You better start with showing your code that reads in those files. Its pretty unclear what you do with reading, copying, pasting and such.

Comment: It looks as if this is not a programming question.

Comment: The size of the file is 19KB.

I have not personally coded these apps so I don't have the code for them.